# Bash script, crate and import sample database

Tags: mysql

I have da_admin and password stored in `my.cnf` file.

Now I prepare script in custom scripts `.sh` in Direct Admin:

CREATE DATABASE

```
#1
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 ) create ${wpconfigdbuser};
#2
echo "CREATE USER ${wpconfigdbuser} IDENTIFIED BY '${dbpass}';" | mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 );
#3
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${wpconfigdbuser}.* TO ${wpconfigdbuser} IDENTIFIED BY '${dbpass}';" | mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2);
#4
mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 ) $wpconfigdbuser < mydb.sql
```

#1 #2 #3 working correct. I have problem with point #4.

When I try:

```
mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 ) {$wpconfigdbuser} < mydb.sql
```

then return: `no database selected`

When I try:

```
mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 ) '{$wpconfigdbuser}' < mydb.sql
```

then return: `unknow database` '{$wpconfigdbuser}'`

@update
I will try temporary solve this issue to input this database in any way.

```
[root@s1 ~]# mv XYZ.cnf /usr/local/directadmin/conf
[root@s1 ~]# cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/XYZ.cnf
[mysql]
user=da_admin
passwd=asdasdasd
    [root@s1 ~]# nano /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom/domain_create_post.sh
```

I try add:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file= /usr/local/directadmin/conf/XYZ.cnf $wpconfigdbuser  <  mydb.sql
```

After run:

```
 mysql: unknow variable 'passwd=DHSDHSDHASD'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have da_admin and password stored in **my.cnf** file.
> cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/**mysql.conf** | grep ...

Typo?

More importantly, you should not *need* to provide the password argument when invoking mysql.
The whole point of putting the credentials *into* a file in the first place is that they **must not** appear (as arguments) on the mysql command line, where they are *visible* to anyone on the machine that can run a **ps** command!

You should add these entries into a *separate* configuration file, expressly for this purpose, and use the `[--defaults-extra-file][1]` option to tell mysql to "read" this file when it is started:

```
$ cat XYZ.cnf
[mysql]
user=da_admin
password=P@$$w0rd
```

Then

```
#4
mysql --defaults-extra-file=XYZ.cnf  $wpconfigdbuser  <  mydb.sql
```

Note: *No* username argument and *definitely* no password arguments appear in this command line.
Both are read from the specified file.

Comment: Really thank you for your help. I have eaten all my teeth on this for 3 days and I hope it will work now.

Can you just give me a hint to be sure I do all correct: 
[root@s1 ~]# cat XYZ.cnf
cat: XYZ.cnf: No such file or directory
[root@s1 ~]# nano XYZ.cnf  -- create file with da_admin details and save. Ok Now this file I have in root. Now where I should create or move this file XYZ.cnf to mysql ready from --defaults-extra-file=XYZ.cnf ? because in your code not use cat and im not sure where I should move this file XYZ.cnf

Comment: The file needs to be somewhere that can be read by the account invoking mysql (or running your script).  Where the file lives doesn't matter (you can specify a complete path to the file and you can call the file whatever you want).  A good choice would be to put the file into the Home Directory for that account, make it readable only by that account and make it a "hidden" file, just to be safe.  Assuming you want this under the `mysql` account: 
mv  XYZ.cnf  ~mysql/.XYZ.cnf
chown  mysql:mysql  $!
chmod  600  $!

Answer (score 0):

Passwords can have all sorts of nasty characters; don't even think about scripting a way of parsing and passing passwords.

Instead, use `mysql_config_editor` for setting up logins to mysql.  Also, it is more secure.